# How get iscroll effect like ios aplication

Tags: html, mobile, iscroll

This url examples:

[example 1](http://rowboatrevolution.com/2012/02/uitableview-parallax-background-a-la-path/)

[example 2](https://vine.co/v/bdKrALdOheD)

Is possible? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using indicators:

http://iscrolljs.com/#indicators
(last entry of section)

example:

http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/parallax/